# Creating Sudoku generator and validator

Tags: java, sudoku

I've created two classes that contain only sudoku logic. One class `Sudoku` generates sudoku grid and returns `SudokuGrid` object with has specific number of values in it(removing values from filled grid). Second class `SudokuGrid` contains all logic that player needs, checking whether any rules are broken. In my opinion `Sudoku` class turned out great, but `SudokuGrid` class not so much, I tried to clean it up as much as I could and this is best I could do:

`SudokuGrid` class:

```
package application;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class SudokuGrid {

    /**
     * Contains all values that grid can contain
     */
    public enum SudokuValue {
        ONE("1"),
        TWO("2"),
        THREE("3"),
        FOUR("4"),
        FIVE("5"),
        SIX("6"),
        SEVEN("7"),
        EIGHT("8"),
        NINE("9"),
        EMPTY(" ");

        public final String TEXT;

        private SudokuValue(String text) {
            this.TEXT = text;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Helps this class with point creating, validating
     */
    private static class SudokuPoint {

        /**
         * @param point - arbitrary point to check
         * @return true if point is ing grid else return false
         */
        private static boolean isValidPoint(Point point) {
            return point.x < SudokuGrid.ROWS && point.y < SudokuGrid.LINES;
        }

        /**
         * @param line - grids blocks line index(0,1,2)
         * @param row - grids blocks row index(0,1,2)
         * @param index - blocks element index
         * @return point in the grid
         */
        public static Point createBlockPoint(int line,int row,int index) {
            Point point = new Point();
            point.x = (line * BLOCK_SIZE) + (index / BLOCK_SIZE);
            point.y = (row * BLOCK_SIZE) + (index % BLOCK_SIZE);
            return point;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Total lines in a grid
     */
    public static final int LINES = 9;

    /**
     *  Total rows in a grid
     */
    public static final int ROWS = 9;

    /**
     * Height and width of a grid
     */
    public static final int BLOCK_SIZE = 3;

    /**
     * contains sudoku grid values
     * if value is zero then it is not set
     */
    private SudokuValue[][] grid;

    /**
     * Creates new Sudoku grid from existing grid
     * @param grid - filled sudoku grid, can contain empty(0) value
     */
    public SudokuGrid(SudokuValue grid[][]) {
        this.grid = grid;
    }

    /**
     * @param value - new value of grids point
     * @param point - x and y coordinates where new value will be applied
     */
    public void setField(SudokuValue value, Point point) {
        if(SudokuPoint.isValidPoint(point)) {
            grid[point.x][point.y] = value;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Parameters did not pass validation");
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return set of points with make contradiction
     * with sudoku rules. If there are not any contradictions present
     * then returns empty set
     */
    public Set<Point> getInvalidFields() {
        Set<Point> fields = new HashSet<>();
        fields.addAll(_getInvalidLineFields());
        fields.addAll(_getInvalidRowFields());
        fields.addAll(_getInvalidBlockFields());
        return fields;
    }

    /**
     * @return set of points with make contradiction in sudoku grid
     * if there are two same values in LINE returns these values coordinates
     * otherwise returns empty set
     */
    private Set<Point> _getInvalidLineFields() {
        Set<Point> fields = new HashSet<>();

        for(int line = 0; line < grid.length; line++) {
            final int x = line;
            List<SudokuValue> lineValues = Arrays.asList(grid[line]);

            fields.addAll(_getDuplicateIndexes(lineValues)
                .parallelStream()
                .map(y -> new Point(x, y))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet()
            ));
        }
        return fields;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return set of points with make contradiction in sudoku grid
     * if there are two same values in ROW. returns these values coordinates
     * otherwise returns empty set
     */
    private Set<Point> _getInvalidRowFields() {
        Set<Point> fields = new HashSet<>();

        for(int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++) {
            final int y = row;
            List<SudokuValue> lineValues = _getRowAsArray(row);

            fields.addAll(_getDuplicateIndexes(lineValues)
                .parallelStream()
                .map(x -> new Point(x, y))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet()
            ));
        }
        return fields;
    }

    /**
     * @param row - grids row
     * @return new array that will contain all rows values
     */
    private List<SudokuValue> _getRowAsArray(int row) {
        List<SudokuValue> ret = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int index = 0; index < grid.length; index++) {
            ret.add(grid[index][row]);
        }
        return ret;
    }

    /**
     * @return set of points with make contradiction in sudoku grid
     * if there are two same values in BLOCK(3x3) returns these values coordinates
     * otherwise returns empty set
     */
    private Set<Point> _getInvalidBlockFields() {
        Set<Point> fields = new HashSet<>();

        for(int line = 0; line < BLOCK_SIZE; line++) {
            for(int row = 0; row < BLOCK_SIZE; row++) {
                fields.addAll(_getInvalidFieldsInBlock(line, row));
            }
        }
        return fields;
    }

    /**
     * @param blockLine - grids blocks line index(0,1,2)
     * @param blockRow - grids blocks row index(0,1,2)
     * @return set of points from grid that are duplicates in block
     */
    private Set<Point> _getInvalidFieldsInBlock(int blockLine, int blockRow) {
        List<SudokuValue> values = _getBlockAsList( blockLine, blockRow);
        return _getDuplicateIndexes(values)
            .parallelStream()
            .map(i -> SudokuPoint.createBlockPoint(blockLine, blockRow, i))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }

    /**
     * @param blockLine - grids blocks line index(0,1,2)
     * @param blockRow - grids blocks row index(0,1,2)
     * @return all values in the list that are in the block.
     * for example:
     *  4   5   6
     *  0   0   0
     *  1   2   3
     *  will return: [4,5,6,0,0,0,1,2,3]
     */
    private List<SudokuValue> _getBlockAsList(int blockLine, int blockRow) {
        List<SudokuValue> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int x = 0; x < BLOCK_SIZE; x++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < BLOCK_SIZE; y++) {
                list.add(grid[(blockLine * BLOCK_SIZE) + x][(blockRow * BLOCK_SIZE) + y]);
            }
        }
        return list;
    }

    /**
     * @param list - list in which duplicates will be searched
     * @return set of list indexes, that are duplicates for example:
     * [3,4,6,5,3] will return ==> [0,4]
     * note it ignores SudokuValue.EMPTY values
     */
    Set<Integer> _getDuplicateIndexes(List<SudokuValue> list) {
        Set<Integer> ret = new HashSet<>();

        for(int pointer = 0; pointer < list.size(); pointer++) {
            SudokuValue currNumber = list.get(pointer);
            for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                if(currNumber == list.get(i) && i > pointer && list.get(i) != SudokuValue.EMPTY) {
                    ret.add(i);
                    ret.add(pointer);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }

    /**
     * prints grid in console
     */
    public void printGrid() {
        for(int index = 0; index < grid.length; index++) {
            for(int index2 = 0; index2 < grid[index].length; index2++) {
                System.out.print(grid[index][index2].TEXT + "  ");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

`Sudoku` class:

```
package application;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static application.SudokuGrid.*;
import static application.SudokuGrid.SudokuValue.*;

public class Sudoku {

    private Sudoku() {
        throw new AssertionError();
    }

    /**
     * Contains sudoku default(valid) grid values
     */
    private static final SudokuValue[][] grid = new SudokuValue[][] {
        {ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE},
        {FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, ONE, TWO, THREE},
        {SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX},

        {THREE, ONE, TWO, NINE, SEVEN, EIGHT, SIX, FOUR, FIVE},
        {SIX, FOUR, FIVE, THREE, ONE, TWO, NINE, SEVEN, EIGHT},
        {NINE, SEVEN, EIGHT, SIX, FOUR, FIVE, THREE, ONE, TWO},

        {TWO, THREE, ONE, EIGHT, NINE, SEVEN, FIVE, SIX, FOUR},
        {FIVE ,SIX ,FOUR ,TWO, THREE, ONE, EIGHT, NINE, SEVEN},
        {EIGHT, NINE, SEVEN, FIVE, SIX, FOUR, TWO, THREE, ONE}
    };

    /**
     * @param valueCount - number of digits with will be present in a grid
     * @return - SudokuGrid object with will contain random part of this grid
     * empty fields will be set to 0
     */
    public static SudokuGrid getSudokuGrid(int valueCount) {
        SudokuValue[][] grid = _getCopyOfGrid();
        _shuffleGrid(grid);
        _removeFields(grid, (ROWS * LINES) - valueCount);
        return new SudokuGrid(grid);
    }

    /**
     * do not pass objects that you don't want to be changed
     * pass filled grid otherwise it will remove empty(0) values
     * @param grid - sudoku grid from with specified number of fields
     * randomly chosen will be set to zero
     * @param count - number count with will be removed from grid
     */
    private static void _removeFields(SudokuValue[][] grid, int count) {
        Set<Integer> fields = new Random()
            .ints(0, LINES * ROWS)
            .distinct()
            .limit(count)
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());

        fields.stream()
            .forEach( n -> {
                int line = n / LINES;
                int row = n % ROWS;
                grid[line][row] = EMPTY;
            });
    }

    /**
     * @return - copy of this objects grid
     */
    private static SudokuValue[][] _getCopyOfGrid() {
        SudokuValue[][] copyOfGrid = new SudokuValue[LINES][ROWS];
        for(int index = 0; index < LINES; index++) {
            System.arraycopy(grid[index], 0, copyOfGrid[index], 0, ROWS);
        }
        return copyOfGrid;
    }

    /**
     * Randomly shuffles grid swapping whole lines and whole rows in the same block
     */
    private static void _shuffleGrid(SudokuValue[][] grid) {
        for(int block, swapIndexOne, swapIndexTwo, index = 0; index < 1000; index++) {
            block = new Random().nextInt(BLOCK_SIZE) * BLOCK_SIZE;
            swapIndexOne = block + new Random().nextInt(BLOCK_SIZE);
            swapIndexTwo = block + new Random().nextInt(BLOCK_SIZE);
            _swapLines(grid, swapIndexOne, swapIndexTwo);
            _swapRows(grid, swapIndexOne, swapIndexTwo);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param r1 - row one index from grid
     * @param r2 - row two index from grid
     * Swaps two rows with are in the same 3x3 block
     * throws RunTimeException if rows are not in the same block
     */
    private static void _swapRows(SudokuValue[][] grid, int r1, int r2) {
        if (_isSameBlock(r1, r2)) {
            for(int index = 0; index < ROWS; index++) {
                SudokuValue temp = grid[index][r1];
                grid[index][r1] = grid[index][r2];
                grid[index][r2] = temp;
            }
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Rows are not in the same block");
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param l1 - is line one index from grid
     * @param l2 - us line two index from grid
     * Swaps two lines with are in the same 3x3 block
     * throws RunTimeException if lines are not in the same block
     */
    private static void _swapLines(SudokuValue[][] grid, int l1, int l2) {
        if (_isSameBlock(l1, l2)) {
            SudokuValue[] tempLine = new SudokuValue[ROWS];
            System.arraycopy(grid[l1], 0, tempLine, 0, ROWS);
            System.arraycopy(grid[l2], 0, grid[l1], 0, ROWS);
            System.arraycopy(tempLine, 0, grid[l2], 0, ROWS);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Lines are not in the same block");
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param block1 - is block one index from grid
     * @param block2 - us block two index from grid
     * @return - true if lines are in the same 3x3 block
     * false if lines are NOT in the same 3x3 block
     */
    private static boolean _isSameBlock(int block1, int block2) {
        return (block1/BLOCK_SIZE == block2/BLOCK_SIZE && block1/BLOCK_SIZE < BLOCK_SIZE);
    }
}
```

1. What do you think about my implementation? Is there any better one?
2. What about invalid fields methods that return set of `Point` objects? How can I create it better?
3. What about structure of my classes? `static` class inside `SudokuGrid` and how I'm doing with comments?
4. And in general what could be improved?

I'm using Java 8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Parameterized Sudoku

In a standard Sudoku grid,
there should be \$n^2\$ blocks of \$n^2\$ numbers,
typically \$3^2 = 9\$ blocks of \$3^2 = 9\$ numbers,
arranged in a square.
As such, the `LINES`, `ROWS`, `BLOCK_SIZE` variables are a bit confusing,
as they could all be derived from \$n = 3\$.

It would be nice if \$n\$ was a parameter of the Sudoku generator / validator, to work with standard sudoku grids of arbitrary sizes,
instead of using those hardcoded static constants.

#### Class design

The class design and organization have many strange, unnatural elements.
To name just the few most prominent ones:

- `SudokuGrid` hardcodes the game parameters in static constants and an `enum`. This effectively prevents extending the game to other setups with \$n <> 3\$.
- `java.awt.Point` shouldn't be used in this Sudoku model. `java.awt.Point` is a graphical element. To follow proper separation of MVC principles, objects from graphical libraries don't belong here. Just because you want to put `x` and `y` somewhere and there is an existing class, that doesn't make it suitable.

#### Coding style

There are many coding style issues.
To highlight some of the most prominent:

- Creating multiple instances of `Random` is both inefficient and unnecessary. You could create just one and reuse it
- `throw new AssertionError` without a message parameter to explain itself
- It's not a common convention to prefix method names with `_`. Stick to `camelCase`
- Some `for` loops can be replaced with `for-each`
- Some variables are poorly named. For example in `printGrid`, the variable names `index` and `index2` are not good.
- On a class named `SudokuGrid`, the term "grid" in `printGrid` is redundant

Comment: An `enum` is always `static` as there's no way for the singletons to refer an enclosing `SudokuGrid` instance. I guess you mean the OP should add the redundant modifier, but it sounds confusing.

Comment: Worth noting is that using an enum instead of an int nukes the parameterisation for bigger sudokus as well (see your first point)

Comment: You're absolutely right @maaartinus, no, the OP shouldn't add a redundant modifier, I dropped that point from my post, thanks for pointing out.